# new folder doesn't inherit permissions windows server 2008

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, shared-directory

I've a strange case on windows server 2008:
I've a folder (F) contains more subfolders
The server administrator is the owner of the root folder (F)
I gave user X full control on this folder and sub-folders
I gave user Y read and execute permissions on the folder and subfolders

when the user X (who has full control) creates a new folder I find that
user Y has the same permission as on parent folder (F)
but user X (who created the folder) has no permissions on the new folder

it seems like user X doesn't inherit the permissions on the folder he creates 
but user Y does

Any reasoning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out
the problem was that the user X has no permissions on the root
hence when he creates a new folder he got the root permissions which is nothing!